# Custom preference, targetSdkVersion="11": missing indent?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-preferences

I have a couple of custom `DialogPreference` implementations floating around, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/blob/master/19-Alarm/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/TimePreference.java):

```
package apt.tutorial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    private int lastHour=0;
    private int lastMinute=0;
    private TimePicker picker=null;

    public static int getHour(String time) {
        String[] pieces=time.split(":");

        return(Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]));
    }

    public static int getMinute(String time) {
        String[] pieces=time.split(":");

        return(Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]));
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        setPositiveButtonText("Set");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker=new TimePicker(getContext());

        return(picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);

        picker.setCurrentHour(lastHour);
        picker.setCurrentMinute(lastMinute);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            lastHour=picker.getCurrentHour();
            lastMinute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

            String time=String.valueOf(lastHour)+":"+String.valueOf(lastMinute);

            if (callChangeListener(time)) {
                persistString(time);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return(a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        String time=null;

        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue==null) {
                time=getPersistedString("00:00");
            }
            else {
                time=getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            time=defaultValue.toString();
        }

        lastHour=getHour(time);
        lastMinute=getMinute(time);
    }
}
```

They work just fine. However, in an application with `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` defined, on a XOOM, they show up missing the indent when in the `PreferenceActivity`:

[image: PreferenceActivity with messed-up custom DialogPreference]

Also, the font size appears a smidge bigger, at least for the title.

There's nothing in `DialogPreference` where I am really overriding any formatting behavior for that stuff, AFAIK. The preference XML is unremarkable, other than referring to the above class:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="sort_order"
        android:title="Sort Order"
        android:summary="Choose the order the list uses"
        android:entries="@array/sort_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/sort_clauses"
        android:dialogTitle="Choose a sort order" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="alarm"
        android:title="Sound a Lunch Alarm"
        android:summary="Check if you want to know when it is time for lunch" />
    <apt.tutorial.TimePreference
        android:key="alarm_time"
        android:title="Lunch Alarm Time"
        android:defaultValue="12:00"
        android:summary="Set your desired time for the lunch alarm"
        android:dependency="alarm" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="use_notification"
        android:title="Use a Notification"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:summary="Check if you want a status bar icon at lunchtime, or uncheck for a full-screen notice"
        android:dependency="alarm" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

[Here is a link to a project](http://misc.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HCCustomPrefWoe.zip) that contains this custom preference and a simple preference XML file that demonstrates the problem. Even with just two Java classes, the preference XML, and an `arrays.xml` file, I get this phenomenon. [Here is a compiled APK](http://misc.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/scrap-debug.apk) from this project.

Comment: You should go ask Mark Murphy -- he knows everything :)

Comment: @JohnnyLambada: I tried that, but the Green Bay Packers front office refused comment. Oh, wait. You didn't mean http://goo.gl/KNYOu ? :-)

Comment: It's always nice to have the same problem as Mark Murphy. If he can't figure it out easily then I don't feel so bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(cross-posting from the [associated android-developers thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/47c0ebae23a7b864))

OK, I figured it out.

There are three possible constructors on a Preference:

```
MyPreference(Context ctxt)
MyPreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs)
MyPreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

Somewhere along the line, I picked up the pattern of having the
one-parameter constructor chain to the two-parameter constructor
(passing `null` for the 2nd parameter), and having the two-parameter
constructor chain to the three-parameter constructor (passing 0 for
the 3rd parameter).

And that's not the right answer.

I am hoping that the right answer is to only implement the second
constructor, because the correct default style is internal to Android
(`com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle`). The second
constructor is the one used with inflating preference XML.

Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: Is the solution to simply to put "com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle" instead of 0 as the third attribute that's passed to the third constructor?  I had the same problem as you a while back and eventually gave up on it.

Comment: @TenFour04: You don't have access to `com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle`.

Comment: Well that's no fun. I don't understand why certain resources are restricted, and others aren't.  For instance, you can use list_selector_background, but not list_selector_holo_dark. Thanks.

Comment: @Maxim: Yes, implementing the two-parameter constructor to chain to the superclass solved the problem.

Comment: It works if we extend preference from one of standard preferences like EditPreference. What if we what to create a custom layout for our preference and extend it from base Preference class? I can't get it intended. Wondering if you tried case like that?

Comment: @Maxim: I have only used `DialogPreference` as the base class, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Doesn't work for me... This is an old post, but do you think you still have your preference layout file, it doesn't seem to be in the download. Also the solution given by Ruslan works for making the preference normal, but my widget is on the right of the summary not below it and I can't change that.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais: I haven't look at this in years. The only custom `Preference` I still (sorta) have is [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer/blob/master/colormixer/src/com/commonsware/cwac/colormixer/ColorPreference.java) from a discontinued library.

Answer (score 6):

You can dance with `void Preference.setWidgetLayoutResource(int widgetLayoutResId)` method, although I prefer to override `View Preference.onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)` method in my custom Preference class and hack it by adding custom views just below `@android:id/summary` (use hierarchyviewer utility for details).

The complete method is:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)
{
    View ret = super.onCreateView(parent);

    View summary = ret.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
    if (summary != null)
    {
        ViewParent summaryParent = summary.getParent();
        if (summaryParent instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup summaryParent2 = (ViewGroup) summaryParent;
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.seek_bar_preference, summaryParent2);

            seekBar = (SeekBar) summaryParent2.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            seekBar.setMax(maxValue - minValue);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

            statusText = (TextView) summaryParent2.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefValue);

            unitsRightView = (TextView) summaryParent2.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefUnitsRight);
            unitsLeftView = (TextView) summaryParent2.findViewById(R.id.seekBarPrefUnitsLeft);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Source code of my SeekBarPreference class based on code from [http://robobunny.com](http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/) can be downloaded [here](http://riilabs.com/files/seekbar.zip)
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on the emulator. There is no problem with the code that you have given, and all the lines have the same formatting; but they all look more similar (in format) to the third preference (`Lunch Alarm Time`) than the others.

It looks like the other three preferences are getting indented more than required. So, maybe you have some global formatting style that is used, but not picked up by the `TimePreference` preference.

**EDIT**: OK. So, the above is not (completely) true. There is definitely a problem when I tried with the target sdk set to `HoneyComb`. But on setting the theme for the `PreferenceActivity` class as `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"`, there is a consistency in the look of all the preferences as shown below.

[image]

This style looks similar to `Froyo`, but not the `HoneyComb`; in the latter, the title font is smaller and there is more indentation. Probably, the default theme is not being assigned to `Custom Preferences` - just a guess :) A workaround would be to assign the default theme to your preference activity explicitly, but I don't know what the default theme in HoneyComb is (and whether it can be set).

Comment: @Rajath DSouza: I get the same behavior on the 3.0 emulator as I do on the XOOM. What emulator did you try?

Comment: I tried it with the Android SDK emulator with Target set to `Android 3.0 (API level 11)` and Skin to `WXGA`.

Comment: @Rajath DSouza: How completely strange. I have no styles at all in this particular project, so that wouldn't seem like the source of the problem. I'll have to do some more experimenting and try to narrow the problem down a bit.

Comment: @Rajath DSouza: Just to confirm -- you have `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` in your manifest, not just having the build target set to 11, right?

Comment: @CommonsWare: No, it looks like I've been linking with Froyo (remnants from a previous project in Eclipse) all this time. When I did set `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`, I'm seeing the same error you have :D ... Sorry to take you off on a wrong trail.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Please see update above based on some tinkering with styles.

Comment: @Rajath DSouza: Based upon a comment from Dianne Hackborn on the `android-developers` Google Group, this is indeed something tied to the holographic theme that you get by default with `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`. Current indications are that I will need to set the layout for the preference proper (i.e., the stuff that goes right on the `PreferenceScreen`), even though I should be inheriting the right one. I'll be working on this in the next day or two and will update matters here when I have something going. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Rajath DSouza: I figured out the problem -- check out my answer to my question above. Thanks for your assistance with this!

Answer (score 1):

The solution which helped me:

I have replaced

```
public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(ctxt, attrs, 0);
}
```

with

```
public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(ctxt, attrs, ctxt.getResources().getSystem().getIdentifier("dialogPreferenceStyle", "attr", "android"));
}
```

As you can see, I replaced third argument **0** with **ctxt.getResources().getSystem().getIdentifier("dialogPreferenceStyle", "attr", "android")** in the second constructor of custom preference class.

Answer (score 1):

To make the accepted answer more clear. You only need this constructor:

```
public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // this(ctxt, attrs, 0); // wrong
    super(ctxt, attrs); 
}
```