# Making a custom preference look like the standard ones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I've written a custom android seekbar preference object based upon the article here: http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/

For my version I'm creating the preference completely programatically in the project I'm using (ie I have seek_bar_preference.xml, but not an example preferences.xml from the example)

The one thing I'm having an issue with is trying to get it to match up with the default notification layout. E.g. I want to have the same padding, font size, brighter color for the "title" than the "summary" and being able to disable the preference and it look the same as the main android ones.

Is there a particular theme or style I should be using to inherit all the default settings. If possible I don't want to have to have multiple layouts for different versions of android.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757012/custom-preference-targetsdkversion-11-missing-indent/14082812#14082812 I believe it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, that link helped sort the issue