# Remove padding from PreferenceScreen that is created programatically in PreferencesListFragment

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I have settings screen which is `Fragment` extending `PreferencesListFragment`. In which first there is main `PreferenceScreen` in which there are multiple `nested PreferenceScreen` like below layout:

```
<PreferenceScreen>
   //general settings
   <PreferenceScreen android:key="adv_settings">
    //more advanced settings
   </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Main Settings list is looks fine as shown below:

[image: Settings list]

But when i clicked on one of `PreferenceScreen` say "Call" then Call `PreferenceScreen` opens as shown below with added `left and right side padding`.

[image: Call Settings list]

I am using Custom layout for `PreferenceScreen` in which i do not give any padding to layout.

I am creating `PreferenceScreen` programatically

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314845/android-how-to-maximize-preferencefragment-width-or-get-rid-of-margin?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-get-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen) about removing padding by setting padding to `ListView` but i did not helped.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The padding is caused by the parent `ListView` in the `PreferenceScreen` containing your settings. I had the same problem when I created my custom preferences from code. If you are using a `PreferenceFragment` to create your Preferences, just go to the `onActivityCreated` function of the `PreferenceFragement` and do the following to remove the padding:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  View lv = getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  if (lv != null) lv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use `R.id.list` instead of `android.R.id.list`

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer it would be more helpful users.