# Unwanted blank space in PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

In my Android app i've defined a very basic `PreferenceScreen`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/test_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/test_values"
        android:key="key_test1"
        android:title="Test title 1" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="key_test2"
        android:summary="Test description 1"
        android:title="Test title 2" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And implemented the corresponding `PreferenceFragmentCompat` class:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey)
    }
}
```

The dependency i'm using:

```
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0"
```

And the code for the layout that hosts the `Fragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything is working fine, except there's a huge blank space on the left side of each preference:

[image]

What is the cause of this problem and how can i prevent it?

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem is the space for the icons are reserved, even if we use no icons for the preference entries.

Setting the `icon` attribute of the preference to `@null` has no effect.

Setting the `iconSpaceReserved` attribute to `false` solves the problem for the `Preference` items, but it has no effect on `PreferenceCategory` items.

Comment: How did you add the `Toolbar`? Did you added in your layout? Would you paste the layout too? Perhaps added start margin ?

Comment: does this happen even if you remove the list pref? Try starting with something really simple like just the checkbox and one word for the title and one word for the description.

Comment: @Mohsen i've added the code for the layout

Comment: @justanoob Remove this: `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment` and see if it helps. Also, you didn't still migrated to AndroidX but maybe this causes the issue.

Comment: @Mohsen why would i remove that? That's required by the [NavComponent](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/). If i remove it, it breaks the whole navigation of the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to get remove margin/padding in Preference Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-get-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen)

Comment: This is the default as of Android Oreo and has been baked into the Support library.

Comment: @justanoob My point is, why would you use `NavHostFragment` for settings? Also, `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment` it seems like it is introduced in AndroidX dependencies but you're still using Support Library v28 that's why it is weird to me.

Comment: have a look at the post Tejas Pandya pointed too. I'm sure one of the answers will help you.

Answer (score 6):

If using **AndroidX**, add the following attribute to your Preferences (and Preference Categories if needed) in XML:

```
<Preference
    ...
    app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
    .../>
```