# Setting default preference theme on custom preference title and summary

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I want to apply the default preference theme for the title and summary, but on custom preference with a custom layout. This way all of them are the same, it looks better. When using [the preference layout from Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml), the title is too big.

- I tried [using `setWidgetLayoutResource`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082812/5288316). They appear correctly but my widget is on the right and not below the text.
- I tried [using only one constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5792547/5288316) to keep the style. Doesn't work.
- I tried everything on [this website](http://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/) and tried using his code on GitHub. Looks good on his screenshots, not on mine.

What I tried that worked is using `textAppearanceListItem` on the title and `textAppearanceSmall` on the summary. But is this guaranteed to look the same as the other for all phones, all versions? (>=API 21 in my case)

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your preferences to v14 to have material design look, and normal size of titles, follow this:
add in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.4.0'
```

then change your preference theme to the v14:

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">
    @style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material
</item>
```

hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it eventually but it might be in a long before you get feedback.